# File permission vs umask value

Tags: linux, file-permissions

If the umask value is 002 for a user, the directory created will have the permission of 775 & files created will have 664, that is we subtract the umask value 002 from 777 for directories & from 666 for files.

Why 777 for directory & 666 for files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do default file permissions before umask come from?](https://superuser.com/questions/476473/where-do-default-file-permissions-before-umask-come-from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directories must have execute permissions if they are to be traversed. Arbitrary files should not have execute permissions for security reasons.