# where do default file permissions before umask come from?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Where are default permissions for files and directories set before a umask is applied to limit those?

Or are they 0777 by default?

Comment: AFAIK they're set to 777 for directories and 666 for files, not sure where this default comes from though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it's hard-coded (in some sense) into every program that can create files.  I basically agree with @Thor: it's typically 777 for directories ***and executable files*** (i.e., compilers use 777), and 666 for all others (data files, named pipes, "special" (device) files, etc.)  The default mode for file-system sockets would probably have to be hard-coded in the kernel, since AFAIK the `bind` system call doesn't allow the program to specify that.

I said "in some sense" because many programs use library functions (e.g., `fopen` in the `stdio` package) to do file I/O, so in their case the default mode is hard-coded in the library function.

---

That said, it's possible that some versions of *nix have a configuration file somewhere, and some or all programs and library functions read this configuration file to get the default mode.

Comment: so no .h files that would define access rights? wouldn't the permission system have to have such?

Comment: @Gung Foo: I'm not sure what you're asking.  `<sys/stat.h>` defines constants like `S_IRUSR = 0400` and `S_IWGRP = 0020`, but these are for the benefit of programs that want to use the `stat` system function to get a file's mode and interpret it.  Yes, the kernel code uses this `.h` file (or an equivalent one) also, but that wouldn't have to be on an operational system unless it had the kernel source code and was being used as a kernel code development/build/test system.  And, yes, it's possible that some programs get their default mode from a `.h` file -- that's just a form of hard-coding.