# How to set specific file permissions when redirecting output?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, file-permissions

This is probably a duplicate, but all my searches are turning up questions about permission denied errors.

I am running a command in a bash shell. I want to redirect output to append to a file that probably does not exist on the first run. I want to set specific file permissions mode if output redirection has to create this file. Is there a way to do this with one command?

For example, I might try

```
foo >> /tmp/foo.log 0644
```

where `0644` are the permissions I want `foo.log` to end up with. Most commands I've experimented with in bash end up interpreting `0644` as an additional argument to `foo`.

I get the feeling that this is going to take a second command to `chmod` the permissions before or after writing to it.

I am using GNU bash 4.2.25 and Ubuntu 12.04, if that makes a difference - general answers are preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to do it while piping as far as I know, a simple script might be the best solution.

```
if [ -e /tmp/foo.log ]; then
    foo >> /tmp/foo.log
else
    foo >> /tmp/foo.log
    chmod 0644 /tmp/foo.log
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Slowki, that was my hunch as well. I'm going to leave it open for a few days, in the hopes of attracting a guru to enlighten us.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it creates a short time window when the permissions on the file are wrong. I would not use it if the goal is to protect sensitive data.

Comment: This answer works, as far as it goes, but @proski is right:  the ```umask``` answers are better, and one of them should be accepted.

Answer (score 22):

I know it's an old question, but I wanted to add my two cents.

I had the same idea and came up with a solution similar to [BowlesCR](https://superuser.com/a/704958/371413).
The problem with his solution was that my command (`foo`) wouldn't work if I changed the umask before running it, so this is my take on the problem:

```
foo | ( umask 0033; cat >> /tmp/foo.log; )
```

Here, `umask` only affects the redirection to `foo.log` in the subshell. Everything else remains unaffected.

A bit convoluted, but it works.

Comment: Very nice and effective :) Just can't be used with stderr redirection on top of stdout redir.

Comment: Note that the set user file-creation mask might be ignored when there's an ACL (Access Control List) active in the corresponding directory, as it is the case in VS Code dev containers. This isn't an issue with the other solutions that execute `chmod`.

Answer (score 6):

Without true scripting, you can chain a bit:

```
touch /tmp/foo.log; chmod 0644 /tmp/foo.log; foo >> /tmp/foo.log
```

Effectively similar to [Slowki's answer](https://superuser.com/q/704910/150988#704916), but condensed into a one-liner.

The only other thing I can think of is tinkering with the umask. Best to do this in a subshell so it doesn't pollute the current environment:

```
(umask 0033 && foo >> /tmp/foo.log)
```

Two issues with that, though.

1. Umask can't raise the permissions above the level specified in the `creat()` syscall (0666 appears to be what Bash uses).
2. This won't change the permissions on an existing file (because `umask` applies only to file *creation*).

Comment: I'm still new enough to *nix that the umask is still a bit of magic to me. Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to read up on it.

Comment: Hmm … Still allows an unprivileged process from opening the file and later read its content.

Comment: (1) Congratulations on finding an *interesting,* useful use of `cat`.  (Although this doesn’t follow the standard pattern of useless uses of `cat`.)  (2) I presume that you meant to say that bash defaults to mode ***0666*** when creating files, and so I edited your answer to say so.  (See [this](https://superuser.com/q/476473/150988 "Where do default file permissions before umask come from?"), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/274100/23408 "What are the conventional file permissions per filetype before  umask is applied?")  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165240/23408 "facl ignoring the “x” permission but only on files").)  And the question specifically mentions mode 0644.  So a `umask` value of 22, 23 or 32 would work as well, in this context (you don’t need to use leading zero(s); when modes and `umask` values are specified numerically, they are always interpreted as octal).  ```22``` is more commonly, conventionally used.

Comment: @Feuermurmel: So what? The question explicitly calls for mode 644.  We have to assume that the OP *knows* that 644 means world-readable and intended to make his information public.

Comment: @Scott I wrote that comment a long time ago. I have _no_ idea why I mentioned that. Maybe I was thinking of write access instead …

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect to a script, unlike `umask`, with process substitution and `install` you can also set the execute bit:

```
install -m 755 <(echo commands go here) newscript
```

`<()` places the output into a temporary file, see [Process-Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)

Comment: This worked really well. An example invocation that I used to download and install a gzipped binary in one step: `install -m 755 <(curl -LsSf https://github.com/containers/netavark/releases/download/v1.1.0/netavark.gz | gunzip -c) /usr/bin/netavark`

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: Note that this is specific to `bash`. It also works in `zsh`, but not in `ash`, `dash`, and `fish`. (But I still upvoted this answer because OP specified `bash`.)

Answer (score 1):

When the redirection sets the wrong permissions, e.g.:

```
$ rm capture.*
$ perl -e 'print STDERR "$$ STDERR\n"; print STDOUT "$$ STDOUT\n"' \
                            >> capture.STDOUT 2>> capture.STDERR
$ perl -e 'print STDERR "$$ STDERR\n"; print STDOUT "$$ STDOUT\n"' \
                            >> capture.STDOUT 2>> capture.STDERR
$ ls -l capture.*
-rw-rw-rw- 1 jcookinf jcookinf 22 Jun 12 10:38 capture.STDERR
-rw-rw-rw- 1 jcookinf jcookinf 22 Jun 12 10:38 capture.STDOUT
$ cat capture.*
215 STDERR
216 STDERR
215 STDOUT
216 STDOUT
```

I believe you can use something like xynomorf gave, and address the stderr concern from Orsiris de Jong with a slight modification to use the [bash process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

```
$ rm capture.*
$ perl -e 'print STDERR "$$ STDERR text\n"; print STDOUT "$$ STDOUT text\n"' \
            > >(umask 0033; cat >> capture.STDOUT) 2> >(umask 0033; cat >> capture.STDERR)
$ perl -e 'print STDERR "$$ STDERR text\n"; print STDOUT "$$ STDOUT text\n"' \
            > >(umask 0033; cat >> capture.STDOUT) 2> >(umask 0033; cat >> capture.STDERR)
$ ls -l capture.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 jcookinf jcookinf 32 Jun 12 10:43 capture.STDERR
-rw-r--r-- 1 jcookinf jcookinf 32 Jun 12 10:43 capture.STDOUT
$ cat capture.*
233 STDERR text
238 STDERR text
233 STDOUT text
238 STDOUT text
```

Naturally, use `umask 0077` to get mode `600`
and prohibit any other users from seeing the contents.

Answer (score 0):

My poor reputation prevents me from commenting on another answer, but the security objection on the accepted answer could be handled by creating and setting the mode of the file before redirecting output to it.

```
if ! [ -e /tmp/foo.log ]; then
   touch /tmp/foo.log
   chmod 0644 /tmp/foo.log
fi

foo >> /tmp/foo.log
```