# what is the difference between umask and chmod

Tags: unix

I am completely confused between umask and chmod. Both are used to give permissions to the files. But where exactly is the difference and when to use them.

I have read the online documentation but both are looking same to me.

umask: umask is used to set default file permissions. These permissions will be used to all subsequent files during their creation.
chmod : used to change file and directory permissions.

As per my understanding if for example file test.doc is created.

By default unix gives the file 022 umask code.

Now when I change it to **chmod 666** test.doc I can change the permission level of this file.

Now what if i use **umask 666** for the same file.

What difference it happens when I use **chmod 666 and umask 666**

Comment: `umask` sets an environment variable which automatically sets file permissions for **newly created files**. `chmod` changes the permissions of **existing files**.

Comment: @DavidPostill.  No, `umask`does not set "an environment variable"  What it does do is set the file mode creation mask of the current shell execution environment.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Related: [Where do default file permissions before umask come from?](https://superuser.com/q/476473/354511), [What are the conventional file permissions per filetype before umask is applied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/274100/80216) and [facl ignoring the “x” permission but only on files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165240/80216).

Answer (score 15):

The difference is that `umask` entails only **new files**. As you stated, umask sets the default permissions that a file/directory will have on creation time, but afterwards `umask` doesn't affect them anymore.

`chmod`, however, needs the file be created prior to be run.

Therefore, if you run `umask`, it will have no effect at all on existing files.

Comment: You can't use `umask` on a file, it doesn't have a `file` argument.

Comment: Right, rewrote that part.

Answer (score 10):

`umask` is very different from `chmod`, actually.

1. An important difference hasn't been mentioned yet:
   `chmod` **sets**, but `umask` **clears** (restricts) permission bits. That's why it's called "mask" (as in "bitmask").
2. As David [wrote](https://superuser.com/a/1030111/150263), `umask` is a (process-level) configuration setting, so it's not applied on any specific files (as opposed to `chmod`).
3. Which brings us to another important point: `umask` is not limited to files. It's also applied when creating directories. (See also e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12445961/1479945).)
4. Also important, that the `chmod` command itself is not affected by the currently configured `umask`.

Now, to your example of what would `umask 666` do:

It will tell the current process (for example your shell) that any new filesystem objects should be created with the `R`+`W` bits (4 + 2 = 6) *removed* (from whatever permissions implicitly or explicitly requested upon creation). (So, 666 is not a very practical value, since it only allows the `X` (execute) bits to be set, but for unreadable files...)

E.g.:

```
$ touch foo; ls -la foo
-rw-r--r-- ... foo   <-- default permissions

$ umask 666
$ touch bar; ls -la bar
---------- ... bar   <-- perms. after the new umask (restriction) is set
$ mkdir foodir; ls -la | grep foodir
d--x--x--x ... dir   <-- not very practical for dirs, either

$ chmod 777 bar; ls -la bar
-rwxrwxrwx .... bar* <-- chmod happily ignores the current umask

$ umask 022
$ touch bong; ls -la bong
-rw-r--r-- ... bong  <-- (so, it seems this was the default umask)

$ chmod 666 bong; ls -la bong
-rw-rw-rw- ... bong  <-- no surprise of any kind here
```

Answer (score 3):

#### UMASK = chmod 777 - umask permissions

```
umask 022 => 777 - 022 => chmod 755
umask 077 => 777 - 077 => chmod 700
umask 002 => 777 - 002 => chmod 775
umask 007 => 777 - 007 => chmod 770
umask 027 => 777 - 027 => chmod 750
umask 177 => 777 - 177 => chmod 600
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The default permission for directories/files is umask 022 then, directories are set by default with permission 755 (`drwx-rw-rw`) and files are set with 644 (`-rw-r--r--`).
Basically, you subtract the octal value of the permission you want from 777 for a directory and from 666 for a file. So from the example above:

`(directory) umask 022 => 777 - 022 = 755`

`(file)      umask 022 => 666 - 022 = 644`

You can find the result of the `umask octal` command in the source **when using umask**, depending on the octal and if it is a file or a directory.

**[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3814/userconcept-95347/index.html)**

**However**, if you `chmod 022 <file>` for a directory, you should get this: `d----w--w-` which would not make much sense.

Underneath, you will find a great description of octal value you can retrieve [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122682/11673349) by Somnath Muluk with great sources as well.

```
N   Description                      ls   binary    
0   No permissions at all            ---  000
1   Only execute                     --x  001
2   Only write                       -w-  010
3   Write and execute                -wx  011
4   Only read                        r--  100
5   Read and execute                 r-x  101
6   Read and write                   rw-  110
7   Read, write, and execute         rwx  111
```